# Getting the General Idea of Vector's Classifiers

Tags: algorithm, classification

I have this "weird data" format type. It goes like this.

`[v1, v2, v3, v4... vn]` where `n>0`

now each "v" is a 2*1 vector. Example:

```
v3 = [time stamp, event]. (type [<string>, <string>])
```

Ok now my question is, what kind of [classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) can I use, or is it better to use, with this format of data? For example, will the [KNN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm) be better or [the perceptron algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron)?

Just want to get an idea on how to move on.

Comment: I think that depends on the characteristic of the specific values you will be classifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classification algorithm depends on your task. If you have training data, you can use Bayesian classifier, Neuron Network, Support Vector Machine, k-NN or perceptron. If you just want to discover the structure of your "weird data", try k-means first.